# Import and parse a HTML file from Drive to Sheets

Tags: html, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a bunch of HTML files in the google drive, but I need to extract tables from them and put into Gsheets.

So far I saw `ImportHTML` function but it does not work with the drive link.

How can I import and parse HTML files from my Drive? Thank you

Comment: You can use a combination of `UrlFetchApp.fetch` and `XmlService.parse` with further processing, but it would be laborious. It might be easier to convert the html files to csv files first (e.g. with online converters).

Comment: I need a code solution without leaving to convert the files in online converters. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- You want to put the values of the table from HTML data using Google Apps Script and/or the built-in functions of Spreadsheet.
- The HTML files are put in your Google Drive.

If my understanding is correct, how about this answer? Please think of this as just one of several possible answers.

### Pattern 1:

In this pattern, `IMPORTXML` is used for the tables deployed with Web Apps.

#### Usage:

#### 1. copy and paste the following script to the script editor.

```
function doGet(e) {
  var fileId = e.parameter.id;
  var html = DriveApp.getFileById(fileId).getBlob().getDataAsString();
  var html = "<sample>" + html.match(/<table[\w\s\S]+?<\/table>/gi).join("") + "</sample>";
  return ContentService.createTextOutput(html).setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.XML);
}
```

#### 2. Deploy Web Apps.

1. On the script editor, Open a dialog box by "Publish" -> "Deploy as web app".
2. Select **"Me"** for **"Execute the app as:"**.
3. Select **"Anyone, even anonymous"** for **"Who has access to the app:"**.
4. Click "Deploy" button as new "Project version".
5. Automatically open a dialog box of "Authorization required".

   1. Click "Review Permissions".
   2. Select own account.
   3. Click "Advanced" at "This app isn't verified".
   4. Click "Go to ### project name ###(unsafe)"
   5. Click "Allow" button.
6. Click "OK".
7. Copy the URL of Web Apps. It's like `https://script.google.com/macros/s/###/exec`.

   - **When you modified the Google Apps Script, please redeploy as new version. By this, the modified script is reflected to Web Apps. Please be careful this.**

#### 3. Put the formula.

Please put the following formula to a cell.

```
=IMPORTXML("https://script.google.com/macros/s/###/exec?id=###fileId###","//tr")
```

- `###fileId###` is the file ID of HTML file on Google Drive.

### Pattern 2:

In this pattern, the HTML tables are retrieved from the HTML data, and the tables are put to the Spreadsheet using Sheets API.

#### Usage:

#### 1. copy and paste the following script to the script editor.

Please set the variables of `fileId`, `spreadsheetId` and `sheetName`.

```
function myFunction() {
  var fileId = "###";  // Please set the file ID of HTML file.
  var spreadsheetId = "###";  // Please set the Spreadsheet ID for putting the values.
  var sheetName = "Sheet1";  // Please set the sheet name for putting the values.


  // Retrieve tables from HTML data.
  var html = DriveApp.getFileById(fileId).getBlob().getDataAsString();
  var values = html.match(/<table[\w\s\S]+?<\/table>/gi);

  // Put the HTML tables to the Spreadsheet.
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(spreadsheetId);
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetName);
  var sheetId = sheet.getSheetId();
  var rowIndex = 0;
  values.forEach(function(e) {
    var resource = {requests: [{pasteData: {html: true, data: e, coordinate: {sheetId: sheetId, rowIndex: rowIndex}}}]};
    Sheets.Spreadsheets.batchUpdate(resource, spreadsheetId);
    rowIndex = sheet.getLastRow();
  })
}
```

#### 2. Enable Sheets API.

Please [enable Sheets API at Advanced Google services.](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enabling_advanced_services)

#### 3. Run the script.

When you run the function `myFunction`, the values are retrieved from HTML data and they are put to the Spreadsheet.

### Note:

- These are the simple sample scripts. So please modify them for your actual situation.

### References:

- [Web Apps](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web)
- [Taking advantage of Web Apps with Google Apps Script](https://github.com/tanaikech/taking-advantage-of-Web-Apps-with-google-apps-script)
- [Advanced Google services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced)
- [spreadsheets.batchUpdate](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/batchUpdate)

Unfortunately, from your question, I cannot understand about your actual HTML data. So if an error occurs and this was not the direction you want, I apologize.