# How to use Google apps script to import a fake Excel file (extension xls but mimetype "text/html") into a Google Sheets spreadsheet?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

A website allows me to download files in 'Microsoft Excel format'.

The file has a .xls extension, but if I open it with a text editor it is an HTML file, and Google Apps Script (GAS) says it has mimetype "text/html"

```
function showFileMimeTypesByFolder(folder) {
  const files = folder.getFiles()
  const mimeTypes = []
  while (files.hasNext()) {
      const file = files.next();
      const fileName = file.getName()
      const mimeType = file.getMimeType()
      Logger.log(fileName)
      Logger.log(mimeType)
}
```

I want to use GAS to import the data in the the file into a Google Sheets spreadsheet.

```
const blob = file.getBlob()
const newFile = {
  title : NewFile',
  mimeType : MimeType.GOOGLE_SHEETS
};
      
Drive.Files.insert(newFile, blob, { convert: true });
```

This created a Google Docs file, but I want a Google Sheets file.

Comment: This approach solved my problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59933492/import-and-parse-a-html-file-from-drive-to-sheets